# timing of PageAdapter.Instantiate new item

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In the code pasted below, which works perfectly, the instantiateItem method of the myPagerAdapter class executes AFTER the int myint = 7; instruction.  This is causing me a problem because I want to reference some of the xml pages where the myint = 7 instruction is located but an exception is thrown because the 4 pages of xml are not yet inflated when I try to make those references.

instantiateItem is being called 4 times and it is dutifully inflating each xml page but it is apparently being done asynchronously somehow and far too late.  I need to get the pages inflated synchrnously, before the mint = 7 instruction (actually my other planned code)is executed.  How can I do that?  What's going on?

Thanks, Gary

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PSContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mysevenpanelpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    myPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(adapter); 

    int myint = 7; //just a debug stop
}   

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter 
    implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.left;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.gps;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.map;
            break;
        case 3:
            resId = R.layout.right;
            break;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to get the pages inflated synchrnously

That is not supported.

> before the mint = 7 instruction (actually my other planned code)is executed

That does not mean that you "need to get the pages inflated synchrnously". That means that you need to delay this work until later in the work queue, after the `PagerAdapter` has done its work.

Replacing:

```
mint = 7;
```

with:

```
myPager.post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    mint = 7;
  }
});
```

may suffice.

Either that, or trigger the work from `MyPagerAdapter`, such as doing the work on the pages after you create them.

Comment: but the work I need to do is adjusting widgets and that can only be done from the UI thread.  It's my understanding that code executed  using runnable cannot reference widgets (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html.)  Am I wrong?  Anyway, I'll read your chapter on Dealing With Threads and figure something out.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1058647: "Am I wrong?" -- when you `post()` a `Runnable`, it is run on the main application thread. This is covered **in the very blog post that you linked to**. For example, see the second code example in that post.

Comment: Doing work inside instantiateItem won't work - need to call methods in the main activity.  Putting code inside new runnable causes errors for instance: Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cpin); gets : "The method getResources() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}" and several other errors also.

Comment: @user1058647: "need to call methods in the main activity" -- you are more than welcome to call methods in the main activity from your `PagerAdapter`. "Putting code inside new runnable causes errors" -- that is because you are using inner classes. Change `this.getResources()` to either `getResources()` or `WhateverYourActivityNameIs.this.getResources()`.